# Customizing Rich text editor in Sitecore Pages

Tags: richtext-editor, xm-cloud

Can we modify the rich text editor in Sitecore Pages, or at least add a new Paragraph style under this dropdown?

[image]

As far as I know, in Experience Editor or Content Editor, we can customize this by setting the source field of the rich text field.

Comment: I had a same conversation with the sitecore support, unfortunately, currently it is not possible, it looks like that the options are hardcoded in the angular app.
In our case we wanted to remove some options.

I hope the sitecore pages team implement the Rich text profile soon.

You may want to keep an eye on the releases:

https://developers.sitecore.com/changelog/xm-cloud

Answer (score 0):

1. In the `web.config` file check the value of setting `WebStylesheet`. By default, it is `/default.css`. Open that file (default.css file located at the root folder of the website) and add your CSS classes here like the following:

[image]

2. Open the `ToolsFile.xml` file located at `rootfolder\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\` folder and add CSS class entries in the `<classes>` node like following

[image: ToolFile.xml]

Here `name` property is a text displayed in a dropdown of Apply Css Classes in RichText Editor and the `value` property must be the same as your class name defined in the `default.css file`.

3. Go to the rich text editor field of your template and make sure the `source property` of it is set to either `Rich Text Full or Rich Text Medium`

[image: Rich Text Editor Source Link]

It’s done. Check your item’s rich text editor field to see the list of CSS classes in the dropdown. If the classes are not there, `clear your Sitecore Cache (/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) and browser cache`. If it still does not appear, restart your IIS website.

[image: Rich Text Editor CSS Class]

Reference: [Apply CSS classes in Rich Text Editor](https://learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/apply-css-classes-in-rich-text-editor/)
[Adding custom CSS Class to Sitecore Rich Text Editor](https://therelentlessfrontend.com/2018/03/15/adding-custom-css-class-to-sitecore-rich-text-editor/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like it would work only in the Content Editor and Experience Editor. I am looking for a way to do it in XM Cloud's Sitecore Pages. Thanks for the answer anyway!